# Redirect port 80 to 4848 for external connections

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, reverse-proxy

I have an application run natively on my computer and can access through browser and port 4848 : localhost:4848/xxx/xxx

And I want to share it to other people through my IP. However, ppl can only access my port 80 (I am running apache server). Then pls help me with any suggestion, I am just a Business Analyst, and no much knowledge about network @_@.

Comment: See docs for Apache's reverse proxy functionality - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

Activate mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http on apache. Configure mod_proxy to pass whatever url you like to your application, see mod_proxy documentation for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially describing the necessity for a reverse-proxy. In your particular scenario, you might want to set up a virtual host with a config similar to the following example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName your.domain.com

      ProxyPass / http://localhost:4848/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4848/
      ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it via apache, you can use something like

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/(xxx)/(.+) http://127.0.0.1:4848/xxx/xxx/$2 [P,L]
```

Then - any request done to http://yourserver/xxx/abc will be proxed to http://127.0.0.1:4848/xxx/xxx/abc

Comment: This does not indicate the configuration of a proxy as you say, but a rewrite rule. If OP were to implement what you have described, the user's browser would have its request URI rewritten such that it'd try and make a request from the user's machine itself, not the server.

Comment: P on end means that it will be proxied thought mod_proxy module - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: I stand corrected. However, given that rewrite rules are more commonly applied to more specific conditions (URIs matching a certain pattern, for example) I still question this as being the best solution to the problem.

Comment: yes, it's more flexible than simple proxypass. It allow specify redirect conditions by using rewritecond, and allow pass only specific urls to specific url on application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http on apache and configure mod_proxy like given below:

ServerName your.domain.com

```
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:4848/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4848/
  ProxyPreserveHost on
```